# get the name of the current window in c#

Tags: c#

I am using a timer in c# to obtain the name of the current window, the problem is that the name of Form1 is repeated, the idea of the code is that it only shows the current and not always the same.

The code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nombre1 = "";
    string nombre2 = "";

    const int nChars = 256;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        nombre1 = Buff.ToString();
        if (nombre1 != nombre2)
        {
            nombre2 = nombre1;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(nombre2+"\n");
        }
    }

}
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: GetForegroundWindow just gets the foreground window of your app, not of the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating and destroying the variables on each call, put nombre1 and nombre2 outside the function and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple. Put a hidden field in each page and give it a id with unique value
and retrive it.

Comment: Ehm... a hidden field to a Windows Form?? and how he should retrieve it??

Comment: Then GetForegroundWindow will get the foreground window in the server, not in the client computer :D